# Segmentation fault smart pointers

Tags: c++11, memory-management, smart-pointers

I get an error of" Segmentation fault while accessing address 0x0000000000000078 .(_ZNKSt8_detail15_Hash_code_baseImSt4pairIKmSt10unique_ptrIN10prometheus5GaugeESt14default_deleteIS5_EEENS_10_Select1stEst4hashImENS_18_Mod_range_hashingENS_20_Default_ranged_hashELb0EE15_M_bucket_indexEPKNS_10_Hash_nodeIS9_Lb0EEEm+0x3b)[0x7fff84143cac1]

While debugging it shows an error in the line in function Family::Add(const std::map& labels,
              Args&&... args) in the line->

auto metrics_iter = metrics_.find(hash);

The error says 
SIGSEV, Gegmentation fault 
0x00007fffcfa29ac1 in std::detail::_Hash_code_base>>,std::_detail::_Select1st,std::hash,std::_detail::_Mod_range_hashing,std::detail::_Default_ranged_hash,false>::_M_bucket_index (this=0x86a5878, _p=0x70,_n=1)include/c++/6.3.1/bits/hashtable_policy.h

The code is below->

GaugeFamilyCopy::Add() function

```
   //namespace prometheus
   GaugeCopy* GaugeFamilyCopy::Add()
  { GaugeCopy* ge = new GaugeCopy(gauge_family->Add(mp));
    return ge;
  }
```

Family::Add function

```
 //namespace prometheus
T& Family<T>::Add(const std::map<std::string, std::string>& labels,
              Args&&... args) {
auto hash = detail::hash_labels(labels);
std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock{mutex_};
auto metrics_iter = metrics_.find(hash);
/*some code which returns T& which I didn't include as the error lies before 
it */

 }
}
```

hash_labels function

```
 //namespace detail which is inside prometheus namespace
std::size_t hash_labels(const std::map<std::string, std::string>& labels) 
{
  size_t seed = 0;
  for (auto& label : labels) {
  hash_combine(&seed, label.first, label.second);
  }

  return seed;
 }
```

Also I had assigned gauge_family it's value in this function ->

```
 //namespace MySpace
 void GaugeFamilyCopy::MakeGauge2(std::string s1, std::string s2, const 
 std::map<string,string>& labels, MyExposer* ex)
 {   auto registry = make_shared<prometheus::Registry>();
   gauge_family = & (prometheus::BuildGauge().Name(s1).Help(s2).Labels(labels).Register(*registry)); 
 }
```

where Register function is given below->

```
 //namespace detail nested inside namespace prometheus
 Family<Gauge>& GaugeBuilder::Register(Registry& registry) {
   return registry.Add<Gauge>(name_, help_, labels_);
 }
```

The Add function used above is-

```
  template <typename T>
  Family<T>& Registry::Add(const std::string& name, const std::string& help,
                     const std::map<std::string, std::string>& labels) {
  std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock{mutex_};
  auto family = detail::make_unique<Family<T>>(name, help, labels);
  auto& ref = *family;
  collectables_.push_back(std::move(family));
  return ref;
  }
```

1. GaugeFamilyCopy class defined in MySpace namespace has a private member called gauge_dummy which is of type prometheus::Family*.
2. GaugeCopy classdefined in MySpace namespace has a private member called g of type prometheus::Gauge*.
3. Gauge is a class defined in prometheus namespace.

Family class

```
  //namespace prometheus
 template <typename T>
 class Family : public Collectable {
 public:

 Family(const std::string& name, const std::string& help,
     const std::map<std::string, std::string>& constant_labels);

 private:
 std::unordered_map<std::size_t, std::unique_ptr<T>> metrics_;
 std::unordered_map<std::size_t, std::map<std::string, std::string>> 
 labels_;
 std::mutex mutex_;

 };
```

Comment: Please read up on [mcve] - this is far too much code to be a minimal example of your problem.

Comment: Thanks, have tried to make it as minimal as possible now .

Comment: This misses the minimal mark by a mile and by a year.

Comment: Ok , made more minimal. All the stuff present now is important as all these functions are involved in the call stack and the source of error might be any one of them.

Comment: Try **ONE** code section that can be copied, pasted, and compiled.